# ImageButon inside text input edit text without losing floating labels

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have some edit text with floating labels like the first one in the image

```
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tlIdMode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/signup_edittext_margin_top"
                android:hint="@string/signup_id_mode">

                    <com.vipera.onepay.ui.component.custom.CustomTextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/etIdMode"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:text="@string/signup_nif"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: Img without ImgBtn]

and I want to have an ImageButton on the right side of the edit text like the second one but I am losing the hint and the floating label...

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tlIdNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/signup_edittext_margin_top"
                android:hint="@string/signup_id_number">


                <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <com.vipera.onepay.ui.component.custom.CustomTextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/etIdNumber"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size" />


                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imgClearUser"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etIdNumber"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etIdNumber"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etIdNumber"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_28dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: img with ImgBtn]

I want to have both, imageButton and floating label. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: use clearable edi text https://arunbadole1209.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/how-to-create-edittext-with-crossx-button-at-end-of-it/

Comment: I know how to clear it, this is not my real problem. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FrameLayout and keep these views separately to the child of the layout. Like

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp20"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlIdNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="signup_id_number">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etIdNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="#FF00FF"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgClearUser"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etIdNumber"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etIdNumber"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etIdNumber"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This will work. Here padding with EditText `android:paddingRight="40dp"` will handle the case where, while typing text will not go under close button. You can increase or decrease this value as per your UI requirement.

---

With proper alignment and view's attributes as per your question, answer would be

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/signup_edittext_margin_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlIdNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/signup_id_number">

        <com.vipera.onepay.ui.component.custom.CustomTextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etIdNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgClearUser"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etIdNumber"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etIdNumber"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etIdNumber"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_28dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: @PabloR. Welcome and congratulations you got your solution